# virt-manager | kvm | spice: "Redirect USB device" menu option is greyed out

Tags: usb, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I'm trying to use a Windows 7 64bit image under Ubuntu 16.04 that I was previously using with Opensuse Tumbleweed using virt-manager too. The guest has a USB2 controller.

The VM works except for the fact that I can't redirect my USB devices to the guest. The option in the menu is greyed out. This worked fine on Tumbleweed.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 2):

Your user will probably have to be added to the `libvirtd` group. Then you should reboot for changes to take effect.  Type in the following from a terminal window:

```
sudo adduser $USER libvirtd
```

More information can be found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/libvirt.html).

Comment: I had the same problem a year ago, and I *think* this is what fixed it for me

Comment: My user was already in the `libvirtd` group, and I checked it again doing `cat /etc/group`. It's also in the `kvm` group.

Comment: @JuliánUnrrein You have rebooted your system since it was added to the group?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, running `virt-manager` with `sudo` made the change.

Answer (score 0):

You must add "USB Redirection" to the VM device list.

Comment: I solved the problem by adding 2x "USB Redirection" devices to the VM. After adding 1x "USB Redirection" the menu item was no longer greyed out, but lead to the error message "Not enough USB channels available". After adding a second "USB Redirection" device, it worked.  Pse note that on RHEL8 the "libvirtd" group doesn't exist. RHEL uses "libvirt" group for this.